# Javascript multiselect and autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, html-select

I am looking for a js/jquery plugin for select boxes.

Requirements are as following:

1. Allow multiselection of items, ideally without repetition (remove items which were already chosen)
2. Autocompletion, like in [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) or [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)
3. User should be allowed to enter values, that aren't present in initial selection.
4. It should be able to grind large amount of options fast. Amount is about 3 to 10 thousand.
5. It should be able to handle unicode characters for autocompletion.

I've used [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) before, and it fits on most requirements, except 4 and 5.

Does domething like this exist? Or at least something close and avaiable for forking?

Comment: Are you, in fact, asking for somebody to code it for you against 500 reputation points ?

Comment: Is this a question or a google query ?

Comment: @dystroy no, I am not asking for that

Comment: @Touki, sorry for my bad english? Google would never handle such a detailed query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing that came to mind when I read your specifications was the selectbox that's being used by [Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/)'s [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview). As this is the most userfriendly/goodlooking picker I've come across so far I'll mention it first.

It:

- Allows multiple selections, which are displayed quite handsomely:
  [image]
- Has autocomplete based on a REST service:

[image]

- Allows foreign values to be posted (although JIRA will reject the values after POST in the scenario's I've tried, but that's up to the application's logic ofcourse).
- As it uses REST, the amount of data it's able to process within a reasonable amount of time is all up to your server-side code and server specs.
- JIRA is unicode-proof, so I have no reason to believe this component is not. Note that the server-side REST service should be unicode proof as well, as should the communication between them.

Atlassian calls this component the ["Frother Control" in their API:](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/webtest/framework/component/fc/FrotherControl.html)

> the AJS.MultiSelect JavaScript control. Occasionally they may be referred to as the 'pickers'. But most of the time people just call it the Frother Control™.

I've found some source for the aforementioned [AJS.MultiSelect class](http://code.google.com/p/net-mvc-demo/source/browse/trunk/Research/MultiSelect.js?r=201), but haven't found an included license, so I'm unsure if it's freely forkable at all. I think AJS is Atlassian's own JavaScript library, so it could very well be under a commercial or restricted license.

---

Another thing you could investigate is [Sencha's ExtJS4's ComboBox](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox). ([Example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/combos.html)).

This control is very flexible, extendable ánd forkable.

I've used this ComboBox for various projects in the past, and I can confirm that it does multiselection, foreign values, autocomplete (local and/or server-side) and unicode.

Most Ext components are usable individually, without using the entire framework. We've had some headaches in the past combining Ext with jQuery, but I believe that those issues are a thing of the past.

Comment: It's a shame that my question was closed. I would most probably have chosen your answer as correct one. I'm going to try ExtJS component, and after some reading it looks like it is able match all my needs.